# Understanding MYSQL logs figuring out server RAM And CPU spikes

Tags: mysql

I have been running a dashboard for weeks without issue. Suddenly tonight the site keeps crashing due to MYSQL processes overtaking the CPU and RAM. Can someone help me understand why this may have been ok for weeks and now is crashing the server?

Server is pretty basic - 4gb RAM, 2 cores, SSD HDD> I think the key for me is that this has not been an issue for months and now is without having made any new changes.

```
 [root@host ~]# mysqladmin --defaults-extra-file=/usr/local/directadmin/conf/my.cnf proc stat
    +------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
    +------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 5 | event_scheduler | localhost | | Daemon | 22 | Waiting for next activation | |
    | 184 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Query | 143 | executing | SELECT * FROM orders_new WHERE DeliveryDate &gt;= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) |
    | 195 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 4044 | | |
    | 200 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 4036 | | |
    | 575 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2559 | | |
    | 579 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2548 | | |
    | 607 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2435 | | |
    | 622 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2375 | | |
    | 638 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2318 | | |
    | 680 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2165 | | |
    | 686 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2140 | | |
    | 688 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 2134 | | |
    | 702 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Query | 154 | executing | SELECT * FROM orders_new WHERE DeliveryDate &gt;= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) |
    | 800 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 1813 | | |
    | 837 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 1654 | | |
    | 865 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 1533 | | |
    | 867 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 1528 | | |
    | 922 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 1288 | | |
    | 1189 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 160 | | |
    | 1192 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 149 | | |
    | 1194 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 147 | | |
    | 1196 | da_sso_gZ45Hr1bu | localhost | food_example-site | Connect | 141 | executing | REPLACE INTO orders_new 
    SELECT 
    pm.post_id,
    pm.post_id AS 'Order_#',
    M |
    | 1204 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 105 | | |
    | 1212 | da_sso_gZ45Hr1bu | localhost | food_example-site | Connect | 82 | executing | REPLACE INTO orders_new 
    SELECT 
    pm.post_id,
    pm.post_id AS 'Order_#',
    M |
    | 1216 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 75 | | |
    | 1231 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 45 | | |
    | 1236 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 27 | | |
    | 1238 | da_sso_gZ45Hr1bu | localhost | food_example-site | Connect | 22 | executing | REPLACE INTO orders_new 
    SELECT 
    pm.post_id,
    pm.post_id AS 'Order_#',
    M |
    | 1240 | food_example-site | localhost | food_example-site | Sleep | 15 | | |
    | 1244 | da_admin | localhost | | Query | 0 | starting | show processlist |
    +------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    Uptime: 5887 Threads: 30 Questions: 22748 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 859 Flush tables: 3 Open tables: 780 Queries per second avg: 3.864
    [root@host ~]#
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Consider changing your 
    SELECT * FROM orders_new WHERE DeliveryDate &gt;= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
into 

    SET @myseldate=0;SELECT (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) INTO @myseldate;
    SELECT * FROM orders_new WHERE DeliveryDate >= @myseldate; 

and give us the time differential, please.

Comment: Sorry about the reformatting of scrunched text in the comment handler.  Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE orders_new;

Comment: @wilson thanks not sure by what you mean about giving you the time differential?

Comment: 'Time to complete' differential between the two techniques of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been INSERTing records into your tables during those weeks where everything worked well? If so, your tables may have become large enough that you need to add indexes for your queries to keep working efficiently. This is a very common consequence of success in new database applications. Look up the " slow query log. " Figure out which queries are hammering your system. Then ask other questions if you need help optimizing them.

Your `orders_new` table may need an index on its `DeliveryDate` column.

Try this and see if it helps.

```
CREATE INDEX orderdate ON orders_new (DeliveryDate);
```

And, it looks like your REPLACE INTO query DELETEs and then INSERTs *every row in your table* whenever you run it. That is bound to slow things down. Find another way to do what you need to do there, or at least put a WHERE clause in that query. If you can use UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT instead, do that.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Yes but it's only like 50 records at any one time. The table is about 50 records long still

Comment: Fifty records is nowhere near enough to cause problems.

Comment: So continuing to look into this, it seems that VIEWs I had set up, where a lot of this data pulls from, are now taking between 30-90 seconds to run. For months they have taken less than 1 second. Nothing has changed except an update to MYSQL 8, although that was more than a week ago. Any ideas?

Comment: right which is why I am so perplexed. Half of my views now take more than a minute to load each, when two days ago each could load in one second or way less. Nothing is corrupt supposedly, so what am I missing here?

Comment: It's hard to suggest anything without knowing a lot more about your database. Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info  Then please ask another question about some specific query and give it the [tag:query-optimization] tag.

Comment: doesnt really seem like a query optimization issue given that this has worked and suddenly stopped

Comment: If none of your tables are growing, you're right, it's not a query optimization issue. Have you rebooted your MySQL server machine? Does that help?

Comment: Yes I have:( NO help. Could it be some sort of corruption that isnt showing up and if so, how does one discover it and root it out?

Comment: Try asking the good people at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ .